# R: I would like to plot one categorical column against all other numeric columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have a dateset where the first column represent language and the rest of the columns represent percentage of use of different categories.[first column repesent the language, the rest represent percentages of use](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phjnQNsSawpbX-7TSCVcjWsqHuMAWu14W4RwnCSccFk/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to represent this table in one plot. I thought stacked bars would be the best way. It seems to me that the best way is to represent the columns (other than lang) on the x axes, percentage on the y axes, lang as fill-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `ggplot2` you have to rearrange you data int 'long' format see `?melt`

```
library(reshape2)
data2 <- melt(data)
```

The following will produce a stacked bar chart

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data2, aes(variable, value, fill = Lang)) +
     geom_col()
```

**Edit**

Regarding your error: Make sure you are using the most recent version of `ggplot2` - `geom_col` is a fairly recent addition I believe.

an alternative is to use `geom_bar()` instead:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(variable, value, fill = Lang)) +
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: Thank you..I am getting this error: Error: could not find function "geom_col"

Comment: Here is everything I did:
> library(reshape2)
> data2 <- melt(all_data_percentage)
Using Lang as id variables
> ggplot(data2, aes(variable, value, fill = Lang)) +
+     geom_col()
Error: could not find function "geom_col"

Comment: Are you still having problems?

Comment: I was able to plot.. it is working perfectly now. the only problem is the mismatch between the legend and the stacking? I would like the order of the stacking to be reversed.. thank you

Comment: To change the order of the legend, I think you will have to reorder the factor levels. I think you can also change the way the fills are applied by doing something like `fill = rev(Lang)`. I'm not really able to offer any more help right now, but let me know if you don't get it working, and I'll have another look this evening

Comment: Thank you.. All is working now. I used tidyverse package suggested by @user:1370303 and it worked. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option, using `tidyr` besides `reshape2`

```r
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_delim("Lang  INT DIR ABS LND TOP VER IV  IR  REL
Arabic  39.05   5   0   3.33    44.76   9.76    11.9    11.43   24.29
Kiche   40.95   2.86    0   1.43    29.05   9.76    12.14   4.52    34.76
Spanish 20.45   2.25    2.86    2.04    33.74   13.7    12.07   9.41    40.08
Yucatec 39.56   6.63    13.27   7.86    49.63   11.3    16.46   15.48   25.31
Zapotec 24.79   0.43    51.28   1.07    32.26   9.83    8.76    8.33    4.06", delim = "\t")


df <- tidyr::gather(df, fields, value, -Lang)

ggplot(df, aes(x = fields, y = value, fill = Lang)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great! thank you. there seems to be a problem when doing 'tidyr::gather' .. I get this warning message **attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped**. the plot looks a lot condensed, only two bars appear, one for language and the other for value. see here: [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mBmueQ07fTda6ev_6hc48gMGu1AJOE7kvIjmNITipIE/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Take a look in your data.frame and compare it with mine. Make sure you have the latest version of tidyverse/tidyr. It should work by just copy/paste my code... Maybe in your dataset, you set the variables with different names, "Languages", and then you are doing: tidyr::gather(df, Language, value, -Language), if it is this, change the name of the first variable "Language" for something like fields... tidyr::gather(df, fields, value, -Language). If it still dont work, please, post a reproducible example where the error occurs, so I can reproduce the problem here and help you out.

Comment: thank you. all is working now. I updated both R and the package. I think however the error was a results of running 'tidyr::gather' on the wrong dataset. The only problem that I have now is the y axis range. The values in the stacked bars are percentage.. So it does not make sense to have these percentages added. Here is an updated version of the data set [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phjnQNsSawpbX-7TSCVcjWsqHuMAWu14W4RwnCSccFk/edit#gid=0] and here the newest graph [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mBmueQ07fTda6ev_6hc48gMGu1AJOE7kvIjmNITipIE/edit] Thank you again